# How to access a link as soon as a user registers ( Sign's Up) using devise in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

In my scenario ...when i send a profile link to a user through email and when user who is not Signed In to my website will be redirected to Sign In page before he can access the sent link.

Once user Signs In, he will be redirected to the link i have sent automatically( taken care by Devise automatically).

But what if user is not yet registered and Sign's Up ? In this case, User has to create account and again click on the Link (from email) to view the link ? ..Cant we redirect to that link once user registers as well through devise ?

Any idea on how to tackle this either using params in link sent or something.

Comment: You need to provide more information about the process. After following the new link I am required to sign up. What happens after submitting the registration form?

Comment: once you sign up...you will be redirected to the link for which you have clicked ...for example going to user profile 45 page once you sign up like this link..www.website.com/user/profile/45

Comment: Do you get an e-mail to confirm your new registration? Or immediately after submitting the sign up form you just display that url?

Comment: @PauloAbreu just display that url once sign up ..actually i already have after_sign_up_path but want to override it a user clicks on link and have to signup before proceeding ...Is there any possibility to send params to signIn page or something like ? IS it possible ?

Comment: I'm not following you, sorry. Could you share with me your relevant code? You can add variables to your url.